# How exactly work this iterate mediator in this WSO2 ESB project?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2** and I have the following doubt about an **ESB** project on which I am working on.

I have to iterate on each `<Sample>...</Sample>` element of the following **XML** document (coming from a **DSS** service):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Samples xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <Sample>
                <sample_id>XXX00001</sample_id>
                <processed>n</processed><sample_doi>sampleid001</sample_doi><date>2000-01-01</date><hold_wiews>hold_wiews-0001</hold_wiews><hold_pid>hold_pid-001</hold_pid><hold_name>hold_name-001</hold_name><hold_address>hold_address-001</hold_address><hold_country>001</hold_country><hold_lat>hold_lat-1</hold_lat><hold_lon>hold_lon-1</hold_lon><method>acqu</method><genus>genus-001</genus><species>species-001</species><sp_auth>sp_auth-001</sp_auth><subtaxa>subtaxa-001</subtaxa><st_auth>st_auth-001</st_auth><bio_status>001</bio_status><mls_status>01</mls_status><prov_sid>prov_sid-001</prov_sid><provenance>pr1</provenance><coll_sid>coll_sid-001</coll_sid><coll_miss_id>coll_miss_id-001</coll_miss_id><coll_site>coll_site-001</coll_site><coll_lat>coll_lat-1</coll_lat><coll_lon>coll_lon-1</coll_lon><coll_uncert>coll_uncert-001</coll_uncert><coll_datum>coll_datum-001</coll_datum><coll_georef>coll_georef-001</coll_georef><coll_elevation>1</coll_elevation><coll_date>2001-01-01</coll_date><coll_source>s1</coll_source><ancestry>ancestry-001</ancestry>
            </Sample>

            <Sample>
                <sample_id>XXX00002</sample_id>
                <processed>n</processed><sample_doi>sampleid002</sample_doi><date>2000-01-02</date><hold_wiews>hold_wiews-0002</hold_wiews><hold_pid>hold_pid-002</hold_pid><hold_name>hold_name-002</hold_name><hold_address>hold_address-002</hold_address><hold_country>002</hold_country><hold_lat>hold_lat-2</hold_lat><hold_lon>hold_lon-2</hold_lon><method>acqu</method><genus>genus-002</genus><species>species-002</species><sp_auth>sp_auth-002</sp_auth><subtaxa>subtaxa-002</subtaxa><st_auth>st_auth-002</st_auth><bio_status>002</bio_status><mls_status>02</mls_status><prov_sid>prov_sid-002</prov_sid><provenance>pr2</provenance><coll_sid>coll_sid-002</coll_sid><coll_miss_id>coll_miss_id-002</coll_miss_id><coll_site>coll_site-002</coll_site><coll_lat>coll_lat-2</coll_lat><coll_lon>coll_lon-2</coll_lon><coll_uncert>coll_uncert-002</coll_uncert><coll_datum>coll_datum-002</coll_datum><coll_georef>coll_georef-002</coll_georef><coll_elevation>2</coll_elevation><coll_date>2001-01-02</coll_date><coll_source>s2</coll_source><ancestry>ancestry-002</ancestry>
            </Sample>

            <Sample>
                <sample_id>XXX00003</sample_id>
                <processed>n</processed><sample_doi>sampleid003</sample_doi><date>2000-01-03</date><hold_wiews>hold_wiews-0003</hold_wiews><hold_pid>hold_pid-003</hold_pid><hold_name>hold_name-003</hold_name><hold_address>hold_address-003</hold_address><hold_country>003</hold_country><hold_lat>hold_lat-3</hold_lat><hold_lon>hold_lon-3</hold_lon><method>acqu</method><genus>genus-003</genus><species>species-003</species><sp_auth>sp_auth-003</sp_auth><subtaxa>subtaxa-003</subtaxa><st_auth>st_auth-003</st_auth><bio_status>003</bio_status><mls_status>03</mls_status><prov_sid>prov_sid-003</prov_sid><provenance>pr3</provenance><coll_sid>coll_sid-003</coll_sid><coll_miss_id>coll_miss_id-003</coll_miss_id><coll_site>coll_site-003</coll_site><coll_lat>coll_lat-3</coll_lat><coll_lon>coll_lon-3</coll_lon><coll_uncert>coll_uncert-003</coll_uncert><coll_datum>coll_datum-003</coll_datum><coll_georef>coll_georef-003</coll_georef><coll_elevation>3</coll_elevation><coll_date>2001-01-03</coll_date><coll_source>s3</coll_source><ancestry>ancestry-003</ancestry>
            </Sample>
        </Samples>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To do it I am using the **iterate** mediator (it is working pretty fine), something like this:

```
<iterate expression="$body//ds:Sample" id="ITR_AGG" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
                <target property="sampleData" type="property"/>
            </enrich>

            <!-- Log Sample Data -->
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:sampleData" name="sample data"/>
            </log>

            ...........................................................
            ...........................................................
            DO SOME OTHER STUFF
            ...........................................................
            ...........................................................
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

It works fine but I have some doubts, I try to explain these doubts.

The **iterate** mediator implements the **Splitter enterprise integration pattern **, it is used to s**plits the message into a number of different messages derived from the parent message**.

Ok, so I am splitting the original message that basically is contained into the `<soapenv:Body>---</soapenv:Body>` container into the 3 `<Sample>...</Sample>` separated message.

It works but why the iterate expression defined into the **iterator** mediator:

```
<iterate expression="$body//ds:Sample" id="ITR_AGG" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
```

is **$body//ds:Sample**?

Ok so I think that I have to use the **ds:** prefix because it is coming from a data service (tell me if I am doing wronga assertion). But what exactly represent the **$body** "variable"? (is it something like a variable?)

Is it representing the `<soapenv:Body>` element in which have to be searched the `<Sample>` element that have to be iterated? Or what? In case my assumption is correct how the `<soapenv:Body>` is associated to the **$body** "variable"?

The second doubt is related to the use of the **enrich** mediator contained at the begining of the **iterate** mediator:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
    <target property="sampleData" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

What exactly does? It seems to me that it is copying the current element on which is iterating into a new property named **sampleData**, infact after this mediator the **sampleData** property is logged by a logger and it is printed something like this:

```
sample data = 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Sample xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <sample_id>XXX00001</sample_id>
            <processed>n</processed><sample_doi>sampleid001</sample_doi><date>2000-01-01</date><hold_wiews>hold_wiews-0001</hold_wiews><hold_pid>hold_pid-001</hold_pid><hold_name>hold_name-001</hold_name><hold_address>hold_address-001</hold_address><hold_country>001</hold_country><hold_lat>hold_lat-1</hold_lat><hold_lon>hold_lon-1</hold_lon><method>acqu</method><genus>genus-001</genus><species>species-001</species><sp_auth>sp_auth-001</sp_auth><subtaxa>subtaxa-001</subtaxa><st_auth>st_auth-001</st_auth><bio_status>001</bio_status><mls_status>01</mls_status><prov_sid>prov_sid-001</prov_sid><provenance>pr1</provenance><coll_sid>coll_sid-001</coll_sid><coll_miss_id>coll_miss_id-001</coll_miss_id><coll_site>coll_site-001</coll_site><coll_lat>coll_lat-1</coll_lat><coll_lon>coll_lon-1</coll_lon><coll_uncert>coll_uncert-001</coll_uncert><coll_datum>coll_datum-001</coll_datum><coll_georef>coll_georef-001</coll_georef><coll_elevation>1</coll_elevation><coll_date>2001-01-01</coll_date><coll_source>s1</coll_source><ancestry>ancestry-001</ancestry>
        </Sample>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

that represents the current element on which I am iterating. Is it my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any string for the prefix, just be sure to use the same string after xmlns:

```
xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
```

Ex:

```
<iterate expression="$body//mypref:Sample" id="ITR_AGG" xmlns:mypref="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
```

$body is a predefined xpath expression for synapse that represent the body message:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$body

The enrich mediator:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
    <target property="sampleData" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

Just copy the content of the incoming message, the entire payload including the soapevelop inside a property called sampleData.